# awk: print to file, which name is from variable defined in the command

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm learning `awk`. In trying to find a solution for a question, I came with the next code, but I'm stuck at the end¹. Explanation:

Having `file` with contents:

```
H|20200425|abcd|    # header
R|abc|2019-03-06|100.00
R|abc|2019-03-06|15.00
R|abc|2019-03-06|10.00
```

- Add at the end

  ```
  T|20200425|-count of records-|-sum of 4th column-
  ```
- Direct the output to a file `20190306.txt`, the date of 3rd column, in the format YYYYMMDD.

My attempt:

```c
awk -F'|' '
  # get the date formatted
  NR == 2 { 
    d = $3; gsub(/-/,"",d) 
  } 
  # get the 2nd field of the header
  NR == 1 { 
    a = $2 
  } 
  # if the line starts with 'R', sum the column and get the count of them
  $1 == "R" { 
    sum += $4
    ++c 
  } 
  # print the final line with variables acquired
  END { 
    OFS = "|"; print "T",a,c,sum".00" 
  }1
' file
```

This command gives me the "desired" result:

```
H|20200425|abcd|    
R|abc|2019-03-06|100.00
R|abc|2019-03-06|15.00
R|abc|2019-03-06|10.00
T|20200425|3|125.00
```

The `d` variable is `20190306`.

But the problem, and what I'm asking, is how to redirect this output to the file `20190306.txt`.

---

<sup>¹Sure it is bad coding of course, (*sigh*, brain hurts), but my goal is to keep the question as focused as possible, I'm not asking to point all the mistakes.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print records to a file whose name is stored in awk variable `d` simply by replacing the implicit print action (triggered by the `1` pattern) with an explicit `{print > d}`

The tricky thing is that you don't know the value of `d` until the second record has been processed; so you need to save the header record until then.

So for example:

```
$ awk -F'|' '
  # get the 2nd field of the header
  NR == 1 { 
    a = $2 
    h = $0
    next
  } 
  # get the date formatted
  NR == 2 { 
    d = $3; gsub(/-/,"",d) 
    print h > d
  } 
  # if the line starts with 'R', sum the column and get the count of them
  $1 == "R" { 
    sum += $4
    ++c 
  } 
  {
    print > d
  }
  # print the final line with variables acquired
  END { 
    OFS = "|"; print "T",a,c,sum".00" > d
  }
' file
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your time! I should say that in some on my tests I came to this solution, but I was under the idea that I could accomplish this with just *one print* at the end.